# PHP not checks if there is already a record in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, so I want to do that if by chance the user searched on and the code for it was no longer activated. In this way, I made a simple code:

```
$loginu = $_SESSION['login'];
$query = "SELECT `usrlogin`,`idcode` FROM `aktywacja` WHERE idcode = $numer AND usrlogin = $loginu ";
$result2 = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();
if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
    not found
}
else {
    found
}
```

and crashes me the following errors

> **Unknown column 'Kamil' in 'where clause'
>   Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kod.php on line 56**
>   Where in this case I made a mistake?

Please help,

greet.

Comment: what is the value `$numer` and what is the datatype of `idcode` and `usrlogin`?

Comment: $numer is number int[10] , $loginu is text varchar(20)

Comment: check if `$numer` is getting value or not?

Comment: idcode is int[10] and usrlogin is varchat[20]

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that those strings are wrapped with quotes if they are not integers:

```
WHERE idcode = $numer AND usrlogin = '$loginu'
```

And make sure that this variable `$numer` is indeed defined, since in your question there is no definition of it.

Obligatory note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Here's what it would look like when used in mysqli with prepared statements:

```
$loginu = $_SESSION['login'];
$numer = // make sure this is defined!    

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

$query = "SELECT `usrlogin`,`idcode` FROM `aktywacja` WHERE idcode = ? AND usrlogin = ?";
$select = $db->prepare($query);
// binding them
$select->bind_param('is', $numer, $loginu);
$select->execute();

if($select->num_rows > 0) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your code, however, even as there is no record that is displayed.

Comment: @Kejl could you paraphrase `however, even as there is no record that is displayed.`? sorry i don't understand\

Comment: I have used and I have modified your code and displays despite the fact that there are no records in the database that the record found. My English is not good :(

Comment: @Kejl you're saying that even if the table is empty `num_rows` is greater than zero?

Comment: @Kejl whats the value of `$znaleziono`?

Comment: variable found is the numerical value $znaleziono - 0 when there is no record in the database, or 1 if there were record

Comment: @Kejl i don't think there is a problem in the code anymore, just that its interchanged, i think when numrows is greater than zero it should be `$znaleziono = 1` otherwise zero

Comment: help me fix it somehow and present his version of the code so that the variable $finded (old $znaleziono) = 1 when it finds or 0 if it does not find in the database record

Comment: @Kejl just change them accordingly, or just plain `echo $select->num_rows;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    check this code and if condtion check to not blank a session data.
    and check a query value is yes to found and else to not found print.

    $loginu = $_SESSION['login'];
    if(isset($loginu))
    {
        $query="SELECT `usrlogin`,`idcode` FROM `aktywacja` WHERE idcode='".$numer."' AND usrlogin ='".$loginu."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            echo "found";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "not found";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in you query
WHERE idcode='".$numer."' AND usrlogin ='".$loginu."'